# I did iptables --flush and now my VPS is down and I can't access it even from hosting company's console

Tags: server, iptables, firewall

I had a problem (maybe a bug?) in CSF-LFD that locked my IP out and I couldn't access the site so I logged in from another IP and did `scf -f && csf -r` but this refresh didn't help. I then did `csf -dr ###.###.###.###` trying to "unblock" my original IP and I got a message that my IP couldn't have been removed from the blocked IP list as it wasn't blocked in the first place.

I then did `iptables --flush` and from that moment I did `iptables --flush` I was logged out and now I can't access the VPS from whatever IP... It went fully down. I even can't access it from my VPS hosting company's console. Any ideas what to do? Maybe just to wait?

I would request the hosting company to reboot my server but still do you have any advice?

### Update:

I did csf -x to disable the CSF-LFD functioniality and then my IP was no longer blocked.

It is wired given that when I `csf -dr ###.###.###.###` I got a message that my IP isn't blocked.

Anyway, after doing csf -x I could surf to the websites and login to the VPS without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted the system from the hosting company's power-cycle option. I could then login to the VPS.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you set your default policy to DROP and thus locked yourself out.

If you can not access the machine you need to ask for technical support.

In the future, dont set the policy to DROP, instead make the last rule in your tables REJECT, you will not lock yourself out when you flush

See http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables